# How to patch shutil.move to test some method

Tags: python, testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I need to test a method that would move a file. I don't want the file move operation to actually occur, I just need to know the method under test made the right call to `shutil.move`

What would be the best way to patch `shutil.move` so the method can call it without doing the actual file operation?

I did it this way but is ugly, I'd like to do it using mock library:

```
    real_move = ftp2email.shutil.move
    move_operations = []
    def fake_move(src, dst):
        move_operations.append((src, dst))
    ftp2email.shutil.move = fake_move

    msg_id = '/path/to/message.xml'
    self.ch.mark_message(msg_id)
    self.assertEqual(move_operations,
                        [('/path/to/message.xml', '/path/to/archived/message.xml')])

    ftp2email.shutil.move = real_move
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it using [Mock library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock)

```
@mock.patch('%s.ftp2email.shutil.move' % __name__)
def test_mark_message(self, move_mock):

    self.ch.mark_message('/path/to/message.xml')
    move_mock.assert_called_with('/path/to/message.xml',
                                 '/path/to/archived/message.xml')
```

This is just one way to do it, I can also be done with a 'with statement' or calling the mock methods start and stop.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [mox](https://code.google.com/p/pymox/wiki/MoxDocumentation), it can do that sort of thing.

From the [mox recipes](https://code.google.com/p/pymox/wiki/MoxRecipes).

```
def testFoo(self):
    self.mox.StubOutWithMock(module_to_mock, 'FunctionToMock')
    module_to_mock.FunctionToMock().AndReturn(foo)

    self.mox.ReplayAll()
    ...
    self.mox.VerifyAll()
```